# Creating a loop with an array and a self executing function

Tags: javascript

**Description:**

I have this function that I'm playing around with. The idea is to initiate a list with a self executing function and then recall that self executing function within the self executing function.

```
var arr = [(function(){

    //when first entering here arr is currently undefined

    //here I call an asynchronous function that will start in 1 second
    setTimeout(function(){
        //1 second has passed so arr has been initiated.
        //Notice that arr[Ø] is undefined and arr[1] isn't
        //Why?
        console.log('Why is this: ' + arr[0] + ' and ' + arr[1] + ' isnt ');
    }, 1000);

})(), 2];
```

So in the end I'm trying to create a loop.

**Question:**

Within the self executing funciton I create a setTimeout and wait 1 second for my arr to finish initiating itself. Why is `arr[0]` undefined and `arr[1]` isn't? Is it even possible creating a loop this way?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/1fv4nnrw/2/)

Final working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/1fv4nnrw/7/): Thanks NoDownVotesPlz

Comment: Well, your self-invoking function returns no value. So by default, it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arr[0]` is undefined because the function doesn't return anything in your function,

If you want to show some value you, you should return it from the function after `setTimeout`: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/1fv4nnrw/4/)

```js
var arr = [(function() {



  setTimeout(function() {

    document.write('Why is this: ' + arr[0] + ' and ' + arr[1] + ' isnt ');

  }, 1000);

  return 1 // return here
})(), 2];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. So I could technically return a function that does the setTimeout yes?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/1fv4nnrw/6/ Here is a demo with the update. How could I get this to loop?

Comment: Oh I figured it out! I just need to add arr[0](); Here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/1fv4nnrw/7/ Thanks for your help :)